# Why I am not able to see proper custom dialog Box in Motorola Atrix Emulator?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, dialog, customdialog

I have created Custom Dialog for my application.
While i run that application in normal Samsung Galary Ace then it shows proper in that device but while i am going to run that app in Motorola Atrix then the Custom Dialog Box not seen proper with the border. . .
Please see the Image of Motorola Atrix Emulator with my Custom Dialog in it.
[image]

Should i have to remove the border of the custom dialog or what else i have to do to see only my custom dialog in any device ?
If i have to remove the border from the custom dialog then let me know how ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this has been answered but here is how I did it...

I saw this on all my Motorola phones X2, Razr...Seems to definitely be a bug in the styles for Motorola.

I fixed it by creating my own style and copying panel_background from my \android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\drawable-hdpi and placing it in my drawable.  Eclipse wouldn't compile if I referenced it using @android:drawable/panel_background.

styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/panel_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
</style>
```

Then just call the dialog with the Theme parameter added

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.Theme_CustomDialog);
```

There fixed Motorola issues!

Comment: I can't believe Motorola screwed this up, something so basic...I would like to take what they've done to popups and fix it but can't seem to trace down to the basic files.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can try by removing border.And set `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`
And make sure that you are using a different class for dialog by extending it`.fix the height and with for your dialog and then try`

But as you said it looks different in only Motorola device.Then its difficult to tell what's going wrong.
The important thing i want to share with you.I was developing application for Motorola milestone.After completing it i installed in Tablet.Then dialog size changes and its appearance too.
And this was not only with custom dialog but Progress Dialog in which no properties was set, changes.Hope you got my point.Finally i want to say dialog behave sometimes unexpectedly.

**Edited**

Create a dialog class and its layout

```
public class DisplayDialog extends Dialog implements {
private ImageButton cancel,submit;
private Context context;
private ProgressDialog pd;

public DisplayDialog(Context c) {
   super(c, R.style.Theme_Dialog_Translucent);
    context = c;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    email_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_id);
    cancel = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

}

Then from activity just make its object and call it where ever you want

```
DisplayDialog dd=new DisplayDialog(this);

dd.show()
```

Comment: I am not able to create the New Activity for the every dialog because there are many dialog in My app.

Comment: 2TofeeqAhmed: If i want to remove the Border from my created dialog (which is already in my current activity) then what should i have to do ? Any code or any sample ?

Comment: I do not say to create activity.I am editing my answer to create custom class for dialog and then how to show it.just wait five min.ok?

Comment: Yes, I mean that only. Dont waste time on it. I have already tryed it. but instaed of that i want the dialog in my activity only. So please help me for it. I dont want to create the another class for it.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that there are some troubles in Motorola styles, that override default Android styles. So, you should just override this styles once again.

As for me, I created my own theme and overrided `android:windowBackground` parameter. You can use your own background image, but I just took default image from Android resources. The resulting style looked like this:

```
<style name="Theme.GreenDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/panel_background</item>
</style>
```